# JS CountDown Interval based on start time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown that repeats with a defined frequency (in my example 15min).

The code below working only with counting to times like 16:00, 16:15, 16:30, 16:45, 17:00, etc.

I would like to define a starting time like 16:23, so the countdown will be to that time: 16:23, 16:38, 16:53, etc.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    timer();

    function timer() {
        let $timer = $('.timer');

        let frequency = 15,
            startTime = new Date('2024-02-15 15:23:00');

          const interval = setInterval(function time() {
     
            let currentDate = new Date(),
              currentMin = currentDate.getMinutes(),
              currentSec = currentDate.getSeconds();


              let leftMin = frequency - (currentMin % frequency),
                leftSec = 60 - (currentSec % 60);

              if (leftSec == 60) {
                leftSec = 0;
                if (leftMin % frequency == 0) {
                  leftMin = 0;
                }
              } else {
                leftMin = leftMin - 1;
              }

              /**
               * Format Timer
               */
              if ((leftMin + '').length == 1) {
                leftMin = '0' + leftMin;
              }

              if ((leftSec + '').length == 1) {
                leftSec = '0' + leftSec;
              }

              /**
               * Display Timer
               */
              $timer.html(leftMin + ':' + leftSec);

          }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/matteokrr/pen/JjzxjoK

Comment: You're going to need to introduce an offset when calculating `leftMin` and `leftSec`. As it stands you're just using the minutes passed the hour instead of minutes before/until your start time.